# User-Agent lost after every test run using PhantomJS

Tags: cucumber, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I'm writing a series of automation tests using Cucumber, Capybara, Poltergeist and **PhantomJS** that visit a website, login and check if certain characteristics of the homepage.

At the beginning of my test runs, I write:

page.driver.headers = { "User-Agent" => "Something" }

and everything works well for the first test case.  However, every subsequent test case seems to forget about this user-agent.  Is this expected behavior? Should I have to set the user-agent before every test case? If not, how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: This line is run once for every execution of the entire test suite.  It's right after the poltergeist driver gets setup

Comment: Its a very long and complex suite so showing code might be difficult, but I do know that the driver is not restarted for each suite

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, page is reset for every scenario. One way to accomplish this would be to add a `Before` step, which would run this code for every scenario in some support file:

```
Before do
    page.driver.headers = {"User-Agent" => "Something"}
end
```